# Using Parse.com APP ID and Client ID security issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, parse-platform

Since the APP ID and Client ID can be read easily by anyone, 
anyone can write data to my table easily.

Let's say I have a table(class) called "Comments" and since any user can write data to "comments" it will have to be public readable and writable, 
a hacker can use my app Id and client ID to put tons of data into my comments table(class) and they can call parse 100 times a second.

**If there any good way to deal with this kind of situation?**

Comment: Also one of the big issue is, since a hacker can easily get the app ID and the client ID, and they can easily decompile the codes to find out the Role class names in my app, a Hacker can easily do whatever he wants using my Admin Role.

Comment: Parse's recommendation in that case is that "admin" tasks should be performed using cloud code -  Any user can then make the "admin" request, but your cloud code verifies their status and performs the operation - the app doesn't contain any admin operations or role information

Answer (score 1):

The keys aren't intended to be "secret". It is entirely possible for someone to decompile your app and get them. There are a few things you can do, however, to lock down your app:

Use ACLs to prevent clients from overwriting data they didn't create

Lock down class creation/modification from the client

If you're really concerned about clients modifying data, move all data modification to Cloud Code functions